# John Lee's proof of Transversality Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, transversality

In John Lee's proof, I cannot understand why the equality holds in (6.9).
(and I think only subset relation is needed in the proof.)

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can understand why $dF(T_{(p,s)}W)\subset T_qX$, but I cannot prove the reverse subset relation.

Comment: @DyneSimian As said just before, it is a result given by Problem 6-10.

Comment: but if $dF_{(p,s)}:T_{(p,s)}W\rightarrow T_qX$ is not surjective then $dF(T_{(p,s)}W)\ne T_qX$

Comment: This is actually an error in the book, and it was addressed in the [errata](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/).